# send tx fee with msg.value

Tags: solidity, contract-development

Hi I want to send 1% additional fee with msg.value but it's not working....

I tried to solve but I can't know the reason?
What is the wrong point of my code?

```
contract Trading {
    address public seller;
    struct Product {
        address buyer;
        uint itemId;
        uint price;
        bool isLocked;
    }
    
    modifier buyerCheck() {
        require (msg.sender != seller);
        _;
    }
    
    mapping (uint => Product) buyerInfo;

    constructor() {
        seller = msg.sender;
    }

    function getSeller() public view returns(address) {
        return seller;
    }

    function getBalance() public view returns(uint) {
        return msg.sender.balance;
    }

    function buy(uint _itemId, uint _price, bool _isLocked) public payable {
        require(msg.sender != seller);
        require(msg.sender.balance >= (msg.value + msg.value / 100));
        uint fee = _price / 100;
        buyerInfo[_itemId] = Product(msg.sender, _itemId, _price, _isLocked);
        payable(seller).transfer(msg.value + fee);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Is the cost of the fee supposed to come from the buyer?

You can't make a smart contract that sucks more funds than what a user is sending. Do you realize the security risk if this was possible?
You can't increase the msg.value from the buyer.

You can add to it from your own funds that are already on the smart contract tho.

Or you can calculate the fee in your front end and add it to the cost when you build the transaction for your customers. But that's in your front end

Comment: Aha... Now I can know the problem..... Thanks for your help!

Comment: You are welcome! If you could mark my answer as valid that would be great! Thanks